# MS Access Wildcard not working with MySQL backend

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I just encountered this anomaly when running an update query from Access 2007 with a MySQL backend.

This SELECT Query shows the correct records.

```
SELECT Courses.Print_Quota, Courses.CourseCode
FROM Courses
WHERE (((Courses.Print_Quota)=0) AND ((Courses.CourseCode) Like "%cc*"));
```

Courses.CourseCode is my Primary Key

Now i try this UPDATE Query,

```
UPDATE Courses 
SET Courses.Print_Quota = 100
WHERE (((Courses.Print_Quota)=0) 
AND ((Courses.CourseCode) Like "%cc*"));
```

Access shows the correct records in datasheet view, but when i Run.. it says 0 rows will be updated (which is exactly what happens)

Any ideas why this isn't working ?
(I have plenty of other ways to achieve the result I want, just wondering what's going on here)

Comment: If this is an Access query (not a Pass-Through query), then `*` is the correct wildcard. If the SELECT statement works, but the UPDATE with the same WHERE clause does not, that's very odd. If I had to guess, I'd say it might be a bug in the MySQL ODBC driver. Can you try both queries without the `%`, i.e. `CourseCode Like "cc*"`? And perhaps with single instead of double quotes `CourseCode Like '%cc*'`?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the data returned from select statement so we can use for reproducible example? Does data actually contain '%' sign?

Comment: is `Courses.Print_Quota` a `single float` ? That my cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql don't use `*` change with another `%`

```
UPDATE Courses 
SET Courses.Print_Quota = 100
WHERE (((Courses.Print_Quota)=0) 
AND ((Courses.CourseCode) Like "%cc%"));
```

or nothing forn ending match

```
UPDATE Courses 
SET Courses.Print_Quota = 100
WHERE (((Courses.Print_Quota)=0) 
AND ((Courses.CourseCode) Like "%cc"));
```

Comment: I get exactly the same behaviour with "%cc%"  - thanks anyway

Comment: If the Access database engine runs the query (and passes it to the ODBC driver), `*` is correct.

Comment: I agree.  oddly running the MySQL syntax on the server also has No effect !  yet i can edit the values in the data sheet view :-/

Comment: @jcansell  well inhope my answer is useful for you